# How to dynamicaly edit a mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I want to be able to edit values in a struct.
My struct is declared and mapped like this :

```
struct entityLinks{
        string linksUrl;
        string linksName;
    }
    mapping (uint => entityLinks) allLinks;
```

The only matter is that i don't know how to dynamicly select the proper value in my struct. The only way I found was to pass a _targeted argument to manually select the proper property.

```
   function editEntityLink(uint _entityLinks,uint _targeted,string _content) external onlyOwner() {
            if(_targeted == 1){
                allLinks[_entityLinks].linksName = _content;
            }
            else if(_targeted == 2){
                allLinks[_entityLinks].linksUrl = _content;
            }
        }
```

I want to be able to have something which fit in 1 line without endless if ... 
(Trying to use a string as argument to edit the property don't work)

Thanks , I hope I was clear !

Comment: I don't understand your problem. First targeted and entityLinks are the exact same values, so why do you use both? Moreover, a mapping is a key-pair value, and you use it properly. So what is your problem exactly? Do you want to check if the mapping is empty at theis specific key?

Comment: I am struggling to dynamically target a value for a mapping ! I would be able to edit allLinks[_entityLinks]._dynamicProperty (_dynamicProperty would be an argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of work for this problem and I found nothing that would work. I would suggest the ternary operator, but it fell short for me. The if-else construct might be the way to go friend.